# how to use locale messages in Sequel model validation

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm using the plugin :validation_helpers with Sequel::Model:

```
class User < Sequel::Model
  plugin :validation_helpers

  def validate
     super
     validates_presence [:name, :mail]
  end
end
```

When I show the the validation errors, the English message "is not present" is written, but I'd like to localize the message in other language. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a Rails application? If yes, you can change the messages used by the Sequel's plugin `ValidationHelpers`. To do that, you should do something like that:

Given the following locale file:

```
en:
  errors:
    exact_length: "is not %{exact} characters"
```

You can define your localized messages like that:

```
Sequel::Plugins::ValidationHelpers::DEFAULT_OPTIONS.merge!(
  :exact_length=> {
    :message=> lambda { |exact| I18n.t("errors.exact_length", :exact => exact)}
  }
)
```

For more information, you can got to the official documentation:

http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/ValidationHelpers.html